# Insert into another table by bifurcating a time period

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE consumer_occurrence_restoration_times (
    consumer_id INT,
    start_time TIMESTAMP,
    end_time TIMESTAMP
);
```

where the data is

```
INSERT INTO consumer_occurrence_restoration_times (consumer_id, start_time, end_time)
VALUES
    (1, '2023-09-24 20:00:00', '2023-09-25 12:00:00'),
    (2, '2023-09-24 21:00:00', '2023-09-25 13:00:00'),
    (1, '2023-09-26 20:00:00', '2023-09-28 02:00:00'),
    (3, '2023-09-25 19:00:00', '2023-09-26 10:00:00'),
    (4, '2023-09-25 21:30:00', '2023-09-27 14:00:00'),
    (5, '2023-09-25 21:30:00', '2023-09-25 22:00:00')
```

I want to insert this data into another table tbl_bifuraction **using a query** so that it inserts data for a day, i.e. start_time occurs on same day as end_time not after 00:00:00 hours of next day.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_bifurcation (
    consumer_id INT,
    start_time TIMESTAMP,
    end_time TIMESTAMP,
  isdaydiff INT
);
```

The insert query inserts the data from the consumer_occurrence_restoration_times table into another table named tbl_bifurcation. However, it needs to split the time intervals into separate days and insert them as individual rows, considering a day from start_time to end_time.
Also, isdaydiff goes 1 if some data  has start time as '2023-09-26 20:00:00' and end time is '2023-09-27 20:00:00' but it stays 0 when end time is '2023-09-27 00:00:00'.
consumer_occurrence_restoration_times table has data like this:

```
consumer_id   start_time            end_time
1             2023-09-24 20:00:00   2023-09-25 00:00:00
2             2023-09-24 21:00:00   2023-09-25 13:00:00
1             2023-09-26 20:00:00   2023-09-28 02:00:00
3             2023-09-25 19:00:00   2023-09-26 10:00:00
5             2023-09-25 21:30:00   2023-09-25 22:00:00
```

For example, if start_time is '2023-09-26 20:00:00' and end_time is '2023-09-28 02:00:00', I want to insert rows like this in tbl_bifuraction:

| consumer_id | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-09-24 20:00:00 | 2023-09-25 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2023-09-24 21:00:00 | 2023-09-25 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2023-09-25 00:00:00 | 2023-09-25 13:00:00 |
| 1 | 2023-09-26 20:00:00 | 2023-09-27 02:00:00 |
| 1 | 2023-09-27 02:00:00 | 2023-09-28 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2023-09-28 00:00:00 | 2023-09-28 02:00:00 |
| 3 | 2023-09-25 19:00:00 | 2023-09-26 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 2023-09-26 00:00:00 | 2023-09-26 10:00:00 |
| 5 | 2023-09-25 21:30:00 | 2023-09-25 22:00:00 |

Here, isdaysdiff = 1 (in all rows except first and last) when bifurcation is done, not in all cases.

Comment: I feel like a separate calendar table that contains the start and end time for each day would work very well here. You would INNER JOIN over to that table `ON calendar_table.date BETWEEN DATE(start_date) and DATE(end_date)`. Then your rows will expand on that join to make one for each date.

Comment: Use generate_series() to create a list of dates and join this on your current data.

Comment: Your expected output is incomplete.  Please provide expected output based on the question.

Comment: If I understand the logic correctly:  On tbl_bifurcation, isdaydiff will always be 0 because all of the dates on tbl_bifurcation meet that criteria.

Comment: You need to include the **complete** expected output for the input specified.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Maybe lateral join of current data with generate_series() would be easier

Comment: I have added the expected output.

Comment: Now you have two input tables with distinctly different values.  Also, "For example,..." shows an example from one row, then your output appears to be for unrelated rows.  Or do you expect that one set of start and end dates with no associated id will generate a random list of 9 rows?  Please correct your question.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a recursive common table expression to define each day range, then join to that.

```
CREATE TABLE consumer_occurrence_restoration_times (
    consumer_id INT
  , start_time TIMESTAMP
  , end_time   TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO consumer_occurrence_restoration_times (consumer_id, start_time, end_time)
VALUES
  (1, '2023-09-24 20:00:00', '2023-09-25 12:00:00')
, (2, '2023-09-24 21:00:00', '2023-09-25 13:00:00')
, (1, '2023-09-26 20:00:00', '2023-09-28 02:00:00')
, (3, '2023-09-25 19:00:00', '2023-09-26 10:00:00')
, (4, '2023-09-25 21:30:00', '2023-09-27 14:00:00')
, (5, '2023-09-25 21:30:00', '2023-09-25 22:00:00')
;

CREATE TABLE tbl_bifurcation (
    consumer_id INT
  , start_time TIMESTAMP
  , end_time   TIMESTAMP
  , isdaydiff INT
);


with recursive
range as (
  select cast(cast(min(cort.start_time) as date) as timestamp) as dtstart
  , cast(cast(max(cort.end_time) as date) as timestamp) + interval '1 day' as dtend
  from consumer_occurrence_restoration_times cort
), 
dt as (
  select r.dtstart
  , r.dtstart + interval '1 day' as dtend 
  from range r
  union all
  select d.dtstart + interval '1 day'
  , d.dtend + interval '1 day'
  from dt d
    inner join range r on r.dtend > d.dtend
)

select cort.consumer_id
, case when cort.start_time > dt.dtstart then cort.start_time else dt.dtstart end as start_time
, case when cort.end_time < dt.dtend then cort.end_time else dt.dtend end as end_time
from consumer_occurrence_restoration_times cort
  inner join dt on dt.dtend between cort.start_time and cort.end_time
                or dt.dtstart between cort.start_time and cort.end_time
order by cort.consumer_id
, dt.dtstart
```

Comment: I have edited and added expected output, the current query unfortunately doesn't gives the expected data set