# Insert Query with expected logic to bifurcate table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE consumer_occurrence_restoration_times (
    consumer_id INT,
    start_time TIMESTAMP,
    end_time TIMESTAMP
);
```

where the data is

```
INSERT INTO consumer_occurrence_restoration_times (consumer_id, start_time, end_time)
VALUES
    (1, '2023-09-24 20:00:00', '2023-09-25 12:00:00'),
    (2, '2023-09-24 21:00:00', '2023-09-25 13:00:00'),
    (1, '2023-09-26 20:00:00', '2023-09-28 02:00:00'),
    (3, '2023-09-25 19:00:00', '2023-09-26 10:00:00'),
    (4, '2023-09-25 21:30:00', '2023-09-27 14:00:00'),
    (5, '2023-09-25 21:30:00', '2023-09-25 22:00:00')
```

I want to insert this data into another table tbl_bifuraction **using a query** so that it inserts data for a day, i.e. start_time occurs on same day as end_time not after 00:00:00 hours of next day.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_bifurcation (
    consumer_id INT,
    start_time TIMESTAMP,
    end_time TIMESTAMP,
  isdaydiff INT
);
```

consumer_occurrence_restoration_times table has data like this:

```
consumer_id   start_time            end_time
1             2023-09-24 20:00:00   2023-09-25 00:00:00
2             2023-09-24 21:00:00   2023-09-25 13:00:00
1             2023-09-26 20:00:00   2023-09-28 02:00:00
3             2023-09-25 19:00:00   2023-09-26 10:00:00
5             2023-09-25 21:30:00   2023-09-25 22:00:00
```

The insert query inserts the data from the consumer_occurrence_restoration_times table into another table named tbl_bifurcation. However, it needs to split the time intervals into separate days and insert them as individual rows, considering a day from start_time to end_time.
Also, isdaydiff goes 1 if some data  has start time as '2023-09-26 20:00:00' and end time is '2023-09-27 20:00:00' but it stays 0 when end time is '2023-09-27 00:00:00'.
For example, if start_time is '2023-09-26 20:00:00' and end_time is '2023-09-28 02:00:00', I want to insert rows like this in tbl_bifuraction:

| consumer_id | start_time | end_time | isdaydiff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-09-24 20:00:00 | 2023-09-25 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-09-24 21:00:00 | 2023-09-25 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-09-25 00:00:00 | 2023-09-25 13:00:00 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-09-26 20:00:00 | 2023-09-27 02:00:00 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-09-27 02:00:00 | 2023-09-28 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-09-28 00:00:00 | 2023-09-28 02:00:00 | 1 |
| 3 | 2023-09-25 19:00:00 | 2023-09-26 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 3 | 2023-09-26 00:00:00 | 2023-09-26 10:00:00 | 1 |
| 5 | 2023-09-25 21:30:00 | 2023-09-25 22:00:00 | 0 |

Here, isdaysdiff = 1 (in all rows except first and last) when bifurcation is done, not in all cases.

**Condition for updating isdaydiff**

isdaydiff = 0 is only used when bifurcation of start date and end date is done, and bifurcation is only done when start date and end date does not fall on same day. It has nothing to do with consumer_id. Each row regardless of any data is a seperate row, no issue whatsoever with previous row. But same consumer will only have different rows when start_date in next row is greater than or equal to previous row end_date with same consumer_id.

The fiddle link is added for [bifuracted_query](https://dbfiddle.uk/nI-8QiEQ)

Comment: The sample data block below "consumer_occurrence_restoration_times table has data like this:" does not match the sample data input into the table in "where the data is".  It's interesting that you copied and pasted the question from your previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77173286/insert-into-another-table-by-bifurcating-a-time-period) that had been closed for being incomplete and confusing, but this time it wasn't immediately closed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert into another table by bifurcating a time period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77173286/insert-into-another-table-by-bifurcating-a-time-period)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first insert the records that don't require splitting, then [`UNION ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html#QUERIES-UNION) that with the selection that does. Use [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) to spawn the in-between days. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/EqzVcAjC):

```
INSERT INTO tbl_bifurcation
SELECT *, 0 as isdaydiff
FROM consumer_occurrence_restoration_times
WHERE start_time::date=end_time::date     --the ones
OR (  end_time::date=(start_time::date+1) --that don't require
    AND end_time::time='00:00:00'::time)  --splitting
UNION ALL  
SELECT consumer_id,
  added_date+case when added_date::date=start_time::date 
                  then start_time::time::interval 
                  else '0s'::interval end,
  added_date+case when added_date::date=end_time::date 
                  then end_time::time::interval 
                  else '1 day'::interval end,
  1 as isdaydiff
FROM (
   SELECT *,generate_series(start_time::date,
                            end_time::date,
                            '1 day'::interval) added_date
   FROM consumer_occurrence_restoration_times
   WHERE start_time::date<>end_time::date       --opposite condition
   AND NOT (end_time::date=(start_time::date+1) --so the ones to split
            AND end_time::time='00:00:00'::time) ) a;

SELECT * FROM tbl_bifurcation
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

| consumer_id | start_time | end_time | isdaydiff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-09-24 20:00:00 | 2023-09-25 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 1 | 2023-09-26 20:00:00 | 2023-09-27 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-09-27 00:00:00 | 2023-09-28 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-09-28 00:00:00 | 2023-09-28 02:00:00 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-09-24 21:00:00 | 2023-09-25 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-09-25 00:00:00 | 2023-09-25 13:00:00 | 1 |
| 3 | 2023-09-25 19:00:00 | 2023-09-26 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 3 | 2023-09-26 00:00:00 | 2023-09-26 10:00:00 | 1 |
| 5 | 2023-09-25 21:30:00 | 2023-09-25 22:00:00 | 0 |

1. The `+case` conditionally restores the time part of start and end of the series of timestamps. Everything in between will only use midnights.
2. You can also use [`extract()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) to get dates, times and more from `timestamp`. Since I only needed dates and times and both `date` and `time` have their own types with pre-defined up- and downcasts, I used those instead.

Comment: I think you will agree that the second,fifth and seventh row in the table has wrong data  as end_date is less than start_date and also, the third row with consumer_id = 1 is redundant and shouldn't exist as end_date is not even 00:00:01, so it shouldn't be there.

Comment: in case of second,fifth and seventh row; I think, it should be next day as end_date instead of current value and data will match the desired output as long as the third row in your table can be removed.

Comment: @learner_987 You're right, correction added. I must've lost the 1 day offset differentiating the two case statements when rearranging the code, which is why the date was re-used.